# Get data from same table with the compare of multiple rows?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of comtent like bellow...

```
    ProjectID  |  ParentID  |  Project Name  ...
    ----------------------------------------
         1     |      1     |  Project Name 1...
         2     |      2     |  Project Name 2...
         3     |      3     |  Project Name 3...
         4     |      1     |  Project Name 4 & Sub Project 1...
         5     |      1     |  Project Name 5 & Sub Project 1...
         6     |      1     |  Project Name 6 & Sub Project 1...
         7     |      4     |  Project Name 7 & Sub Project 1 & Sub Project 4...
         8     |      4     |  Project Name 8 & Sub Project 1 & Sub Project 4...
         9     |      9     |  Project Name 9...
```

In here **ProjectID** is primary key & **ParentID** indicates the primary or main ProjectID of sub project. If ProjectID = ParentID it means it is primary (main) project

Now the question is if I want to fetch out the sub-projects of sub-projects that means,
If I want to see the sub-projects under **1** and out put'll be ...

```
    ProjectID  |  ParentID  |  Project Name  ...
    ----------------------------------------
         1     |      1     |  Project Name 1...
         4     |      1     |  Project Name 4 & Sub Project 1...
         5     |      1     |  Project Name 5 & Sub Project 1...
         6     |      1     |  Project Name 6 & Sub Project 1...
         7     |      4*    |  Project Name 7 & Sub Project 1 & Sub Project 4...
         8     |      4*    |  Project Name 8 & Sub Project 1 & Sub Project 4...
```

- here 4 is the sub project of 1 and 7,8 are the sub project of 4

How do I compare? Do I have to use #temp for 1 and then consider the primary ID of #temp table? or is there any better solution?

Comment: I would go for Recursive CTE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Great I hope it'll work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve. But the actual solution is given by [Jayvee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2964963/jayvee). Sorry I didnt know the method it calls, so I think I didnt explain it perfectly. Actually I want to use recursion here on aspect of ProjectID.

```
DECLARE @ProjectID int = 1
WITH DirectReports 
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT C.*
    FROM tblProject AS C
    WHERE C.ProjectID = @ProjectID
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition    
    SELECT C1.*
    FROM tblProject AS C1
    JOIN DirectReports AS d ON C1.ProjectID = d.ProjectID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT * FROM DirectReports
UNION ALL
SELECT C.*
FROM tblProject AS C
WHERE C.ProjectID = @ProjectID and C.ProjectID=C.ParentID
```

More elaboration you may find [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).
Thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to find this is to search the `ProjectName` column.  It appears to contains the hierarchy information:

```
select c.*
from content c
where ProjectName+' ' like '%Project 1 %'
```

The additional space is to be sure that `Project 1` does not match `Project 10`.

Comment: ProjectName is just a sample. I am giving ProjectID that means 1. and it fetch all its sub projects + sub projects of sub projects.

Comment: @Borhan . . . I can only go by the data you provide in the question.  The `ProjectName` fields appears to contain the hierarchy information you need.  Getting the project information from there is simpler than using recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below SQL query:

```
select projectid, parentid, projectname
from project_table
where Projectname like '%Sub_Project_1/%' escape '/'
and Projectname = 'Project_Name_1/%' escape '/';
```